# How can I Initialize TIM1 as Capture Interrupt at Channel 4 for CD4060 Pressure Sensor using STM8?

Tags: input, timer, interrupt, stm8

I want to INITIALIZE TIM1 as Capture Interrupt for CD4060 Pressure Sensor.
Can someone help me with this I wanted to know weather my code is correct or if there are some thigs which need to be changed, for capturing Interrupt.

TIM1_CR1=0x01;
TIM1_CR2=0x04;

TIM1_SR1=0x51;
TIM1_SR2=0x10;

TIM1_PSCRH=0x00;
TIM1_PSCRL=0x0F;

TIM1_ARRH=0x3e;
TIM1_ARRL=0x80;

TIM1_CNTRH=0;
TIM1_CNTRL=0;

TIM1_CCMR4=0x80;

TIM1_CCR4H = 0xFF;
TIM1_CCR4L = 0xFF;